# How to have 3 sections in a row

Tags: css, html, class, inline

Ok this is what I have..

```
         <section id = "main"><!--main section -->
            <h2> Latest Work... </h2>
            <section class="examples"><a href="#"><img src="images/eg.jpg" alt="example"></a> </section>
            <section class="examples"><a href="#"><img src="images/eg.jpg" alt="example"></a> </section>
        </section><!-- end of main section -->
```

Ok now I dont understand how I would line these 3 sections up in one line.. ive tried display: inline-block; etc nothing seems to work. do i need to target the section part in the css file or the img? or both? help! lol thanks :)

ok iv managed to do that with all your help.. how would i center them now?

Comment: Lists of sections inside sections containing images... Sounds like your semantics need re-thinking.

Comment: what would the right way to do it? add the images into divs?

Comment: the reason I have put them in sections is because they may all not include images inside them.. I have done this just as an example..

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
​h2, .examples​ {
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;    
    display:block;
}​
```

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/Phenix/Mwtdb/

Comment: ahh great.. gona try it out now

Comment: I've decided to change the sections into spans.. any idea how I would center them now? ive tried text align in the main section.. wont work

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid html i think, change to this

```
<section id = "main"><!--main section -->
            <h2> Latest Work... </h2>
            <span class="examples"><a href="#"><img src="images/eg.jpg" alt="example"></a> </span>
            <span class="examples"><a href="#"><img src="images/eg.jpg" alt="example"></a> </span>
        </section><!-- end of main section -->
```

Comment: is it wrong to use sections? Because the images will be showing examples of work so thought it was 3 different sections.. not sure though..

Answer (score 0):

At the end, add:

```
<br style="clear:both"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css. Change the width as required

```
 h2,.examples
    { {float:left;
    margin-left:10px}}
```